# UITableViewCell - initWithFrame:reuseldentifer: is deprecated

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm receiving a warning saying `initWithFrame:reuseldentifer:` is deprecated. I don't know what this means. How do I fix this with error free?

```
// If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[ThreadSCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

I'm using [this code](http://blog.tolik.org/2010/04/iphone-sdk-sms-balloon-cell.html).

Answer (score 2):

It means that Apple recommends you don't use `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` for creating cells anymore. This can be for a number of reasons, like there's a method to replace it that's better, or that that method can cause problems, or that it will be removed.

In this case, the designated initializer is `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` now, you should use that one to get rid of the warning.

Comment: The deprecated method was really bad because the frame parameter was always ignored (the width equals to the table view's width, the height is set by the delegate, the origin is computed by the table view itself). They just deprecated the API because it made no sense.

Comment: If you change to ... cell = [[[ThreadSCell alloc] initWithStyle:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];  The error appears.

Comment: @user1273250 Well of course, because the style parameter is not a CGRect. You should look up that method in the UITableViewCell header or class reference to understand how to use it.